# Remote PGSQL Server Issue

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently using pgsql server 12.15.3
When I connect to PGSQL server remotly I get [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhCQG.png) you see , also when I trie to open schemas in PGSQL Server remotly I get the error message
'column "wait_event_type" does not exist LINE 10: wait_event_type || ': ' || wait_event AS wait_event,'

I have not tries anything yet since I could not find any solution on the internet.

Comment: wait_event_type exists since version 11, you must be working on something older. Version 11 is EOL since 2023.

Comment: 1) There is no `pgsql server 12.15.3`. As of Postgres 10, the version numbers are X.x. 2) The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is, you are connecting  to a server that your version of `pgAdmin` does not support. FYI, **do not** use images, copy and paste the text into your question. 3) Try using `psql` to connect to the remote server, it is backward compatible.

Comment: Do not link to the error message, as people with the same error message will not find your question and will not benefit from the posted answers. Please copy&paste the error message in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Confirm the version of PostgreSQL you are using:

SELECT version();

Upgrade PostgreSQL

Comment: This is not an answer and also is potentially dangerous to the OP's data. Blindly upgrading can go wrong quickly.